# Child got A+ blood group when both parents are O+

Tags: blood, genetics

Based on my understanding of Blood group tables, such as the one below a child can only get O blood group when both parents have O as their blood groups. In a close relative's case, while her parents and two siblings have O+ as their blood groups, she ended up having A+. We are puzzled as how this could happen?

[image: Parent-child Blood Group Chart]

Comment: Blood ABO typing is not as simple as shutterstock makes it. There are weak A types etc. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6910028/

Comment: A much more common occurrence than rare blood groups is non-paternity. Use care when suggesting this to relatives.

Comment: Someone needs to point out that one possible explanation is that the father isn't who they think it is.

Comment: I am completely sure that the OP, the relative who got the blood test result, and absolutely everyone they have discussed it with has considered (assumed) that paternity is the issue. I expect that is why OP is asking, to see if there is any other explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although such cases are undoubtedly rare, they are not impossible. Here's [a case report from 2005](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1365-3148.2005.00603.x):

> Apparent deviation from Mendelian rules of blood group inheritance is rarely observed. Blood group O parents with children expressing weak A subgroups have occasionally been described but not explained. A detailed serological investigation of such a family is described here. [...]
>
> The propositus' RBCs were very weakly agglutinated with monoclonal anti-A but distinctly with polyclonal anti-A,B, i.e. typical for Ax. Serum anti-A1 (titre 4) and -B were present. Her parents' blood groups were both clearly O, with titres of serum anti-A1, and -A at 16 and 4, respectively. Adsorption/elution studies demonstrated A antigen on the daughter's cells only. The ABO genotypes were: mother, AxO1; father, O1vO2; and propositus, AxO2. The Ax allele was an A1-O1v hybrid allele with a crossing-over breakpoint between positions 235 and 446 in intron 6 (Ax-4). Compared to the A1 glycosyltransferase, this allele predicts a protein with two amino acid substitutions (Phe216Ile and Met277Val) known to yield either weakly expressed or no A antigen on RBCs.
>
> This study suggests that the nature of the ABO allele in trans can influence A antigen expression, a phenomenon previously described as allelic enhancement (or reinforcement).

Answer (score -3):

Theoretically, if both parents are O+, there is no chance of an A+ child.  Type O blood is recessive, and must be homozygous to exhibit as the blood type.  However, if one parent was mistyped, and carried O but had type A blood as his/her dominant type, then of course this would be possible.

Allegedly there are occasional genetic mysteries called "throwbacks" (cf. "[atavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atavism)") which present unusual anomalies (e.g. two Caucasian parents having a black child).  But aside from something of this nature, of whose possibility in this case I am uncertain, some of the possible causes might include:

- One parent actually has type A blood (could have had blood mistyped, or parent was misidentified).
- The child was mistyped, and needs to be retested.
- Blood samples on test day were cross-labeled (mixed up).
- The parents brought home the wrong infant from the hospital.
- Etc.

Was the blood test done at school and the child, too afraid of the finger prick, begged some friend to "help"?  There are a number of possibilities that one might consider, but to have an A+ child from two O+ parents is not one that I would consider.

Neither does the Red Cross, though they do seem hesitant to make a perfectly definitive declaration on account of potential issues with testing, as seen in their remarks below their blood-type graphic (available [HERE](https://www.redcrossblood.org/donate-blood/blood-types.html?icid=rdrt-blood-types&imed=direct&isource=redirect)).

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide citations to back your claims?